# Can i use old ecu on replacement enigine with same model number

Tags: engine, electronic-control-module, opel, swap, zafira

so basically head gasket went in my zafira, engine number z16xep.  After all the damage to pistons and cylinder etc it is cheaper to get replacement engine.. that's what I did. Its the same 1.6 twin port ecotec engine with same model number z16xep.. now my question is can I just use my old ecu on the new engine (plug and paly) without programming? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same exact model engine then you can use the ECU without any changes or re-programming. Mechanically it's the same, and the ECU has no way of knowing that it's a different engine as it only sees what is electrically connected to it, as in sensors and data inputs.

Comment: Happy days, that's a relief .. would I need to use old wiring loom? Thanks for your answer though buddy 